# Deleting CSV the entire row if text in a column matches a specific path or a file name

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell so please try to explain things a little bit too if you can. I'm trying to export the contents of a directory along with some other information in a CSV .

The CSV file contains information about the files however, I just need to match the FileName column (which contains the full path). If it's matched, I need to delete the entire row.

```
$folder1 = OldFiles
$folder2 = Log Files\January
$file1 = _updatehistory.txt
$file2 = websites.config
```

In the CSV file, if any of these is matched, the entire row must be deleted. The CSV file contains FileName in this manner:

```
**FileName**
C:\Installation\New Applications\Root
```

I've tried doing this:

```
Import-csv -Path "C:\CSV\Recursion.csv" | Where-Object { $_.FileName -ne $folder2} | Export-csv -Path "C:\CSV\RecursionUpdated.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But it's not working out. I would really appreciate help here.

Comment: Does the filename match exactly? If it is only a part of it, use: $_.fileName -notlike "$folder2*"

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Yes the file names will match exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to match only parts of the full path, so you should use [`-like` or `-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators) operators (or their negated variants) which can do non-exact matching:

```
$excludes = '*\OldFiles', '*\Log Files\January', '*\_updatehistory.txt', '*\websites.config'

Import-csv -Path "C:\CSV\Recursion.csv" | 
    Where-Object { 

        # $matchesExclude Will be $true if at least one exclude pattern matches
        # against FileName. Otherwise it will be $null.
        $matchesExclude = foreach( $exclude in $excludes ) {
            # Output $true if pattern matches, which will be captured in $matchesExclude.
            if( $_.FileName -like $exclude ) { $true; break }
        }

        # This outputs $true if the filename is not excluded, thus Where-Object
        # passes the row along the pipeline.
        -not $matchesExclude  

    } | Export-csv -Path "C:\CSV\RecursionUpdated.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This code makes heavily use of PowerShell's implicit output behaviour. E. g. the literal `$true` in the `foreach` loop body is implicit output which will be automatically captured in `$matchesExclude`. If it were not for the assignment `$matchesExclude = foreach ...`, the value would have been written to the console instead (if not captured somewhere else in the callstack).

Comment: The variables containing the "parts" of the full path are being loaded from elsewhere (a JSON file actually). So I cannot enter the names of the files to be matched exactly because I need to load the variables first. Is there a way I can store these variables in a similar way like you have done with `$excludes`?

Comment: @Scripter9700 Should be possible. How to do it, depends on how the JSON is structured. You may post this problem as a second question. The current question has been answered.